# How to rename variables in a method by Mono.Cecil v0.9.5 in C#

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I want to rename variables that defined in a method.

suppose my Method is:

```
public void PrintWelcome() {
    StringBuilder myMessageBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int linesCount = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < linesCount; i++) {
        myMessageBuilder.Append(Console.ReadLine());
        myMessageBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    Console.Write(myMessageBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Then in another project with Mono.Cecil v 0.9.5 i open my Assembly and then
i want to rename `myMessageBuilder` and `linesCount`  by these codes:

```
foreach (MethodDefinition methodDef in typeDef.Methods) {
    if (methodDef.HasBody) {
        foreach (var variableDef in methodDef.Body.Variables) {
            variableDef.Name = GetRandomName();
        }                                    
    }
```

but my variables name didn't change and when i printed  `variableDef.Name` it printed `" "`.

Can anybody help me for renaming my method variables?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables don't *have* names once compiled. Information like that is stored in the pdb file, not the assembly itself.